# Kendo UI File Upload works on Test but not on server (IIS 6.1)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, kendo-ui

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3, Kendo UI, and IIS 6.1.

I am using the Kendo File Upload control.  When I test on my local machine, everything works fine, the file gets uploaded as expected.  When I deploy to my server, the file upload does not work.  I already checked permissions of the folders.

I already searched stackoverflow for other people having similar problems but found nothing that solves mine.  I actually stripped all of the code from my action method that receives the file upload just to see if it would hit the action method and it does not.

Here is my Kendo Upload control:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
   .Name("files")
   .Async(a => a
   .Save("SaveForm", "Form")
   .Remove("RemoveForm", "Form")
   .AutoUpload(true)
  )
   .Events(events => events
   .Success("UPLOAD_onSuccess")
   .Error("onUploadError")
   .Select("UPLOAD_onSelect")
  ))
```

Here is my action method in my controller:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SaveForm(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        return Content("TEST STRING");

    }
```

My expectation is that I would get "TEST STRING" returned, but I don't even think it's hitting my controller.  This works fine in my local environment.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: how it does not work? did you check what server returns?

Comment: the Kendo code automatically passes control into the onUploadError jquery function.  It passes in an object named e, and there is nothing useful in e to help me troubleshoot the error.  Just the fact that an error has occurred.

Comment: Use Fiddler to see the actual server reply for the async request. Probably your server is throwing 500 error with some exception description. Start from looking on that error.

Comment: I installed fiddler and the server is throwing a 200.  But the for some reason the file is not uploading and it's landing in my onUploadError jquery function.

Comment: That sounds wrong. If server return is 200, then javascript should not show the error. Are you sure you are looking on the correct request?

Comment: Yes, I was.  But when I put my code back in the action method, it threw a 500, but there weren't any details.  With the above action method (empty), it threw a 200 and still triggered the jquery error function.

Comment: according to documentation (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/upload/overview) you should return "empty string to signify success of upload". So this could be a reason for your javascript going into error function. And when you get actual 500, but no results, are your custom error errors in "RemoteOnly"? switch that in web.config to "Off" and see the exception message.

Comment: I just changed it to return empty string.  Let me look into the "RemoteOnly" switch

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I just got the Kendo part of it working right.  It looks like there was a problem with my code that was within the action method.  I do some processing to the file before I move it on the server.  I am going to now break it into two steps to hopefully get some more meaningful error messages.